# Drag-n-Drop in an Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to AngularJS and Ionic framework. I am developing an app in ionic framework in which I need to implement a very basic drag-n-drop functionality. e.g. dragging text from one  to another .

I am NOT dealing with lists, just simple text dragging only. I have followed some online tutorials but none of them actually worked with my ionic app.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: All I need to accomplish is drag text from one div container and drop it in another div container.

Comment: Please go to https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable. I think its help you.

Comment: @Neotrixs Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.